# How can I get the output of method/function with the input of dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, methods

In my code, I want to input dictionary and get the output of function/method.

For example,

```
# with this input, 
ranparams ={
    "scale": (0.04, 0.08),
    "radius": (4000,6000),
}

# get this ouput,
model.scale.range(0.04, 0.08)
model.radius.range(4000, 6000)
```

Are there any examples for this?

Comment: Are you trying to call those two functions separately?

Comment: What code have you tried to get this? You *do* know about `print()` don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a starred expression to unpack the tuples as arguments:

```py
ranparams ={
    "scale": (0.04, 0.08),
    "radius": (4000,6000),
}

model.scale.range(*ranparams["scale"])
model.radius.range(*ranparams["radius"])
```